# change time plugin in to 24 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Currently i am using 12 hours format which means AM,PM concept ,I want to change this timepicker in to 24 hours and remove AM ,PM.

html code

```
<div id="time-range">
<p>Time Range: <span class="slider-time">9:00 AM</span> - <span class="slider-time2">5:00 PM</span>

</p>
<div class="sliders_step1">
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
```

css code

```
    #time-range p {
    font-family:"Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: 8px;
    background: #D7D7D7;
    border: 1px solid #BABABA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 #CFCFCF inset;
    clear: both;
    margin: 8px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range {
    top: -1px;
    height: 100%;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 8px;
    font-size: .7em;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #5BA8E1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #AAD6F6 inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #81B8F3;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgi…pZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #A0D4F5), color-stop(100%, #81B8F3));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A0D4F5, #81B8F3);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A0D4F5, #81B8F3);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #A0D4F5, #81B8F3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #A0D4F5, #81B8F3);
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F9FBFA;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgi…pZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #C7CED6), color-stop(100%, #F9FBFA));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C7CED6, #F9FBFA);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C7CED6, #F9FBFA);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C7CED6, #F9FBFA);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #C7CED6, #F9FBFA);
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0 -1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0 -1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0 -1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .3s;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .3s;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    cursor: default;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -4px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    background: #30A2D2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(22, 73, 163, 0.7) inset, 0 1px 0 0 #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(22, 73, 163, 0.7) inset, 0 1px 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(22, 73, 163, 0.7) inset, 0 1px 0 0 #FFF;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
    top: -.5em;
    margin-left: -.6em;
}
.ui-slider a:focus {
    outline:none;
}

#slider-range {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#time-range {
  width: 400px;
}
```

js code

```
    $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    values: [540, 1020],
    slide: function (e, ui) {
        var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
        var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

        if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
        if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
        if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
        if (hours1 >= 12) {
            if (hours1 == 12) {
                hours1 = hours1;
                minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
            } else {
                hours1 = hours1 - 12;
                minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
            }
        } else {
            hours1 = hours1;
            minutes1 = minutes1 + " AM";
        }
        if (hours1 == 0) {
            hours1 = 12;
            minutes1 = minutes1;
        }



        $('.slider-time').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1);

        var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
        var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

        if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
        if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
        if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';
        if (hours2 >= 12) {
            if (hours2 == 12) {
                hours2 = hours2;
                minutes2 = minutes2 + " PM";
            } else if (hours2 == 24) {
                hours2 = 11;
                minutes2 = "59 PM";
            } else {
                hours2 = hours2 - 12;
                minutes2 = minutes2 + " PM";
            }
        } else {
            hours2 = hours2;
            minutes2 = minutes2 + " AM";
        }

        $('.slider-time2').html(hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
    }
});
```

What change can made this timepicker in to 24 hours

Comment: I believe you need to replace 12 by 24

Comment: yes,How can i replace this -@Nevermore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look at any sections that manipulate the Hours > 12. There's no need to do this if you want 24-hour time. I'm pretty confident you can discard the two blocks below.

```
if (hours1 >= 12) {
     if (hours1 == 12) {
         hours1 = hours1;
         minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
     } else {
         hours1 = hours1 - 12;
         minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
     }
 } else {
     hours1 = hours1;
     minutes1 = minutes1 + " AM";
 }
 if (hours1 == 0) {
        hours1 = 12;
        minutes1 = minutes1;
 }

if (hours2 >= 12) {
        if (hours2 == 12) {
            hours2 = hours2;
            minutes2 = minutes2 + " PM";
        } else if (hours2 == 24) {
            hours2 = 11;
            minutes2 = "59 PM";
        } else {
            hours2 = hours2 - 12;
            minutes2 = minutes2 + " PM";
        }
    } else {
        hours2 = hours2;
        minutes2 = minutes2 + " AM";
    }
```